# Is Possible to make filter on calculated column??

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, filter, calculated-column

I have Date column in list on based it i have create two calculated column month and year.

Now i am trying to get data for particular month and year so I have give filter in REST query but it give Bad request error.

my query like below:

```
?$select=Type,EmpName/ID,EmpName/Title,Time&$expand=EmpName&$filter=(Month+eq+10)+and+(Year+eq+2016)
```

Comment: Any help from my answer?

Comment: @AtishDipongkor thanks for replay and answer. but  i didn't want to use CAML query.

Comment: Then `$filter` on calculated is not possible

Answer (score 3):

`$filter` does not work with calculated columns. In that case you have to write a CAML query and make a POST request.

## Request End-Point

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('List Name')/GetItems
```

## CAML

```
var query = "<View>"+
              "<Query>"+
              "<Where>" +
               "<And>"+
                  "<Eq>"+
                   "<FieldRef Name='Month'/><Value Type='Text'>10</Value>"+
                  "</Eq>"+
                  "<Eq>"+
                   "<FieldRef Name='Year'/><Value Type='Text'>2016</Value>"+
                  "</Eq>"+
                "</And>"+
              "</Where>"+  
              "</Query>"+
              "</View>";
```

**PS:** Check the CAML query before using it.

## Request Body

```
var data = {  
    query: {  
        __metadata: {  
            'type': 'SP.CamlQuery'  
        },  
        ViewXml: query 
    }  
};
```

Find other limitation of REST API over [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-rest-api-limitation).