# Calculate total hours in SharePoint List based on Months

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, jquery

I have a three columns in SharePoint list:

1. Hours (Numbers column)
2. Date (Date only)
3. Months (calculated column depends on Date field)

Using a dropdown selection, when I select any month in dropdown, it should calculate total number of hours are employee's are working in that particular month. Using Jquery

Comment: Please share the code example what you have tried so far.

Comment: Still I didn't write any code for that. Actually I need to add total values in Hours field, when date column value and month value are same.

Comment: You can use the `onchange` event of dropdown and then multiply the month value with `30*24`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In HTML file:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://techindyapvt.sharepoint.com/sites/RnD/SiteAssets/MonthFilter/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://techindyapvt.sharepoint.com/sites/RnD/SiteAssets/MonthFilter/jquery.SPServices-2014.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://techindyapvt.sharepoint.com/sites/RnD/SiteAssets/MonthFilter/sharepointplus-4.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://techindyapvt.sharepoint.com/sites/RnD/SiteAssets/MonthFilter/MonthsFilter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://techindyapvt.sharepoint.com/sites/RnD/SiteAssets/MonthFilter/Date.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<body>
<label style="margin:10px; font-size:15px; font-weight:bold;"> Total Hours Per Month : </label>
<select id="CategoryFetchingHrs" style="width:125px; height:35px;">
                <option value="Select Month">Select Month</option>
                <option value="January">January</option>
                <option value="February">February</option>
                <option value="March">March</option>
                <option value="April">April</option>
                <option value="May">May</option>
                <option value="June">June</option>
                <option value="July">July</option>
                <option value="August">August</option>
                <option value="September">September</option>
                <option value="October">October</option>
                <option value="November">November</option>
                <option value="December">December</option>
            </select>
<input id="txtHrs" type="text" style="width:80px; color:black; font-weight:bold;" disabled>
</body>
```

**In JS File:**

```
var getformattedMonth;
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#RnDdateFetchingHrs").datepicker();
        $("#txtDate").datepicker(); 
            $("#RnDdateFetchingHrs").datepicker({
            minDate: 0,
            maxDate: "+2M"
            }); 
            $("#txtDate").datepicker({
            minDate: 0,
            });  
    loggedInUser = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
            fieldNames: ["ID", "Title"],
            debug: false
        });
});
$(document).on('change', '#CategoryFetchingHrs', function(e) {
var MonthVal = $(this).val();
var TotalAmount = 0;
$().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            listName: "RCCP Timecard",
            CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Month' /><Value Type='text'>" + MonthVal + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Month' /><FieldRef Name='Hours' /></ViewFields>",
            completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                    var Amount  =0;
                    Amount = parseFloat($(this).attr("ows_Hours"));
                    if(!isNaN(Amount))
                    {
                    TotalAmount += Amount;  
                    }
                });
            }
});
$("#txtHrs").val(TotalAmount+" hrs");
});
```

I think it will work for you..

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See this

```
 $("#monthDropdownId").change(function () {
    var month = $('#monthDropdownId').val();
    var hours = month*30*24;
    //...assign to Hours column
});
```

Here I am trying to get the value from the `monthDropdownId` with `onchange` event.
After getting the `month` value I got the `hours` value by `month*30*24`. Now this `hours` you can assign to the `Hours` column.

Answer (score 0):

You could use rest api to filter items when month changing mentioned by Harsh, then calculate the total hours.

Filter based on calculated column.

[Is Possible to make filter on calculated column??](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200539/is-possible-to-make-filter-on-calculated-column)